# Default ItemTemplate of Controls like ListBox/ListView

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Where can I find the default `ItemTemplate` of controls like `ListBox`/`ListView`? There's nothing in MSDN about this.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!--What's the default value of this?-->
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: what about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms788747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms750821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [WPF Tutorial](https://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html):

> **Data Templates** give you a very flexible and powerful solution to replace the visual appearance of a data item in a control like ListBox, ComboBox or ListView.
>
> If you don't specify a data template, WPF takes the default template that is just a TextBlock.

I.e. the default should be:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Read more on [`DataTemplate`](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html)